# Generating multiple apk

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, apk

I want to generate multiple apk with single build.
all apk with different server URL.

The application is like loading webview, and the URL used for webview is different for all generated apk.

For example, apk 1 webview is loading url like `www.url_1.com`,
apk 2 webview is loading url like `www.url_2.com`

Something like this.
Difference between all apk is only Webview URL, not anything else.

Thank you in advance. Waiting for answer.

You can check this repo If I have done any mistake : https://github.com/asa-odoo/Testing-Apps/tree/master/WebViewDemo

Comment: You should check about BuildTypes or productFalovors: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is to create different `flavors` of your app, and then use flavor-specific `resources` (in separate `values.xml` files for each flavor for example) to specify different URLs for different flavors.

e.g.

**app/src/flavorOne/res/values/values.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="webviewUrl">www.url_1.com</string>
</resources>
```

**app/src/flavorTwo/res/values/values.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="webviewUrl">www.url_2.com</string>
</resources>
```

**app/build.gradle**

```
productFlavors {
    flavorOne {}
    flavorTwo {}
}
```

And then you can just reference `webviewUrl` id in your code, and it will resolve to the correct value for each APK.

**Additional resources:**

- [developer docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants)
- [this
  article](https://www.androidauthority.com/building-multiple-flavors-android-app-706436/)
  for detailed steps in the IDE.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer. I follows steps as per your guidlines and [article] (https://www.androidauthority.com/building-multiple-flavors-android-app-706436), But it only generates one apk. Didn't know if I miss something.

Comment: `gradlew assembleDebug` should now build 2. `gradlew assembleFlavoroneDebug` should build just `flavorone`. This is not working?

Comment: Can you please check this github repo If I had made any mistakes : https://github.com/asa-odoo/Testing-Apps/tree/master/WebViewDemo

Comment: Your `app/build.gradle` is missing `productFlavors { facebook{} google{} instagram{} }`. See here for more info: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants

Comment: Yeahhh..!!! Thank you so much :) Now, It's working. Thank you @kenny_k You made my day

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
buildTypes {
 debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            buildConfigField("String", "BASE_URL", "\"http://dev.yoururl.com"")
            buildConfigField("String", "API_KEY", "\"ABCXYZ123TEST\"")
        }
        release {
            buildConfigField("String", "BASE_URL", "\"http://prod.yoururl.com"")
            buildConfigField("String", "API_KEY", "\"ABCXYZ123PROD\"")
        }
}
```

Check the Android documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants

Comment: Thank you @kike I will also try this one.